# TypeError: this.isModified is not a function - Mongoose Models FindOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I want to hook into when the address changes, so I can alert users of update.

However, due to my app logic, the update object always is like this:

```
Location.findByIdAndUpdate( options.location_id, { name: options.name, address: options.address }).exec()
```

Now I could rewrite this by first looking up the location, before this to first check if options.address is different, and exclude it from the update if it's this is the same.

Then I could use

```
LocationSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
 if (typeof this._update.address == undefined) {
   return next();
 }

  console.log("address updated, time to notify");
  next();
});
```

But I'm wondering if I can do something similar to common logic used in pre save methods, like this:

```
LocationSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
 if (!this.isModified('address')) {
   return next();
 }

  console.log("address updated, time to notify");
  next();
});
```

But unforuntately, TypeError: this.isModified is not a function.

Doing this inside the model logic would be easier and save a call.

Comment: The basic reason is that since this happens on the "server" mongoose actually has no handle to the "document" being modified. I sort of wonder about why you would "need" a hook here because you "should" be using operators like `$set` with such a method and you would "know" if you actually modified the address in the first place since that would be the instruction. I see the case of not wanting to call such a notify explicitly, but it's part of the trade off for atomic modifiers IMHO.

Comment: You sound very informed but I can't quite grasp what you mean.

My aim is to email users about the address being updated.

Sometimes the location.address and/or location.name is updated. How can using $set help me identify when address being called?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I fixed with this.

```
 userSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
 // if password is not updated 
 if (!this._update.password) {
   return next()
 }

 bcrypt.hash(this._update.password, 8, (err, hash) => {
   if (err) {
     return next(err)
   }
   this._update.password = hash
   next()
 }) 
})
```